# Filename cannot be empty error while uploading image

Tags: php, html, string, error-handling

i am storing 2 images in to my database . if i uploaded 2 images at a time then its storing successfully . but if try to upload only  image1 or if i try to upload image2 or if i not uploaded any image then i am getting this Warning

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\print\main.php on line 24

My code is :

```
    <label for="certificate">Upload Scaned Document:</label>
     <input type="file"  name="image" /> 
                 OR
     <label for="certificate">Upload Scaned QR Code</label>
     <input type="file" name="QRimage"  />
```

php code:

```
    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

    $QRimageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"]);
    $QRimageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["QRimage"]["tmp_name"]));
```

even i tried with this all so:

```
    if(isset($_FILES["image"]) && (!empty($_FILES["image"])) && ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0))
```

And

```
   if((isset($_FILES["QRimage"]["size"])) && ($_FILES["QRimage"]["size"] > 0))
```

then i can overcome that warning .

If i tried to upload Image1 then.

```
         Notice: Undefined variable: QRimageName in C:\wamp\www\print\main.php on line 59
         Notice: Undefined variable: QRimageData in C:\wamp\www\print\main.php on line 59
```

If i tried to upload Image2 then .

```
         Notice: Undefined variable: imageName in C:\wamp\www\print\main.php on line 59
         Notice: Undefined variable: imageData in C:\wamp\www\print\main.php on line 59
```

I am feed up with this error please help me how to solve this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$imageName = "";
$imageData = "";
$QRimageName = "";
$QRimageData = "";
if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){ 
    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
}
if(!empty($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"])){
    $QRimageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"]);
    $QRimageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["QRimage"]["tmp_name"]));
}
```